# Postgres - Unique constraint with multiple columns and NULL values

Tags: postgresql

I have problem with Postgres Unique constraint with multiple columns that may contain NULL value.

Let's assume this situation:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test (
  foo TEXT,
  bar TEXT,
  UNIQUE (foo, bar)
);

INSERT INTO test
VALUES 
  ('foo', NULL),
  ('foo', NULL),
  ('foo', 'bar'),
  ('foo', 'bar')
ON CONFLICT (foo, bar) DO NOTHING;
```

Insert will insert ('foo', 'bar') once and ('foo', NULL) twice (even though the intuition says it should insert once).

In this scenario solution is pretty straightforward. I could just add unique index

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX indx ON test (foo) WHERE bar IS NULL;
```

But the problem starts when there is more columns and with different types (not only text).
Let's say we have 10 columns and 9 of them can have `NULL` value.
Maybe I could solve it with big amount of constraints, but it's not convenient at all.

Is there easier way to keep uniqueness for a row like that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For PostgreSQL v15 or better, see Naeel's answer. For lower versions, try the following:

An alternative to the good solution of forbidding NULLs is to create a unique index.

All you need is a value that is guaranteed not to occur in your data set (in my example `'@@'`):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON test (
   coalesce(foo, '@@'),
   coalesce(bar, '@@')
);
```

Comment: Haven't thought of coalesce with a unique constraint so far, thats in fact with the combination of non-nullable defaults a pretty solid way of handling this issue!

Comment: If you can manage to set the column `NOT NULL`, forget the `coalesce`.

Comment: Thank you that's perfect solution for my case. Unfortunately I need columns with values with `NULL` and there are different column types, so this will work perfectly for me

Comment: @puchal, pay attention to the new feature of PG 15 — F292 «Unique null treatment».

Answer (score 5):

BTW, since version 15 Postgress supports optional feature of SQL specification F292 «Unique null treatment». It allows to control behavior NULL values in unique constrains

```
create table ... (
  ..........,
  UNIQUE NULLS [NOT] DISTINCT (...)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You might consider the column definition in general, as both are stated as texts, you can just let them be NOT NULLABLE and provide a DEFAULT value as ' ' (empty string). This way you can be sure, that foo does not get saved twice. Also NULL values are not that good in practice, because its just a sign that there is a MISSING value.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE test (
  foo TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  bar TEXT DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (foo, bar)
);
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion, but what with a case where columns can be different type then text (for example integer that can be missing). I'm sorry I didn't make it clear enough in question. I'll edit it accordingly.